# COM add-in EOL from outlook ecosystem

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, office-addins

We use com add-in to extract meeting information and create meetings in our custom product. We use a 3rd party dev-express control. Recently we have seen limited support of COM+ add-in in office ecosystem and we realize that office-JS add-in are the future. With recent updates, we have seen some issues that suggest that COM is dying sooner than we expected.

We have a huge customer base that are using COM and in case this is phased out by Microsoft we will have to go back to these customers with a solution. We are working full force on replicating all the features of COM+ add-in in office-JS addin however this is a huge investment in terms of effort.

What are the tentative timelines for phasing out COM add-in from outlook ecosystem and is there any future roadmap for COM+ addins.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is a COM addin, not a COM+ addin. Secondly, Microsoft has not announced any plans to stop supporting COM addins in Outlook. It is a mature technology that does not really need much improvement.

If you are running into a particular issue, it might be better to post a specific question rather than make a sweeping generalization.

Microsoft is investing most of its resource into the new JS based addins, which are supported on all platforms where Outlook runs. Unfortunately, functionality wise, web addins API is not anywhere the decades old Outlook Object Model and COM addins.